# Constructing Javascript Call back: Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I make a series of calls to youtube like:

```
function getVideos() {

    for(var i=0; i<queryArray.length; i++){
        var queryUrl = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q="+queryArray[i]+
              "&max-results=1&orderby=relevance&alt=json-in-script&format=5";

     $.get(queryUrl, function(){ 
    constructHtml(data, i);
    });

    }

}
```

The idea is to pass the data returned from the $.get call into a function that will then display the appropriate html.

I have

```
function constructHtml (data, idNum) {

// do some stuff
}
```

But firebug is telling me "data" in constructHtml is not defined. I am guessing Im using the callback in jquery the wrong way. i'd appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you lacked the `data` parameter in the callback function

```
$.get(queryUrl, function(data){ 
    constructHtml(data, i);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$.get(queryUrl, function(){
```

to

```
$.get(queryUrl, function(data){
```

You will see from the [docs for .get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) that the success function can include other useful params `success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) A callback function that is executed if the request succeeds.`

Answer (score 1):

You’ve missed a bit:

```
$.get(queryUrl, function(data){ 
  constructHtml(data, i);
});
```

You need to specify that your anonymous callback from the AJAX load takes a data variable. This will then be passed through to your function/

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass data in the callback function

```
$.get(queryUrl, function(data){ 
    constructHtml(data, i);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `data` parameter in the anonym function:

```
$.get(queryUrl, function(data){ 
    constructHtml(data, i);
});
```

But also `i` will always be `queryArray.length` cause the function will be executed after the for loop is runned.

You can use jQuery's `each` to get `i` in a local scope:

```
$.each(queryArray, function(i, value) {
    var queryUrl = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=" + value + "&max-results=1&orderby=relevance&alt=json-in-script&format=5";

    $.get(queryUrl, function(data){ 
        constructHtml(data, i);
    });

});
```